# Wagtail {{document.url}} is returning a 404 for user-uploaded files, in production

Tags: django, document, wagtail

I've inherited a Wagtail CMS project but have been unable to solve an issue relating to document uploads.

Having uploaded a file through the CMS, it arrives in the documents directory `/var/www/example.com/wagtail/media/documents/test_pdf.pdf` which maps to the `/usr/src/app/media/documents/test_pdf.pdf` directory inside the docker container.

In the front end (and within the Wagtail dashboard) the document.url resolves to `https://example.com/documents/9/test_pdf.pdf/` which returns a 404. Obviously the model number segment is missing from the file path above, but I read [on a forum](https://groups.google.com/g/wagtail/c/g90DyrxAX9w) that

> In Wagtail, documents are always served through a Django view (wagtail.wagtaildocs.views.serve.serve) so that we can perform additional processing on document downloads

so perhaps this, in itself, is not an issue.

There are a couple of lines in `urls.py` file which look correct:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap),

    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

    #    url(r'^pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    ...
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in `base.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

So, my hunch is one of either:

1. Uploads being stored incorrectly, in a single folder rather than in subdirectories by model
2. The routing to this “virtual” directory is broken, so it’s breaking at the "check permissions" stage (but I couldn't figure out how routing works in Django) and returning the 404
3. The web server is incorrectly configured, so whilst the “virtual” URL is fine it’s actually the file URL which is broken and THIS causes the 404 (my nginx contains a /media/ location but not a /documents/ location, as I would have expected)
4. Something else entirely (my next step is to pull a copy down to my own machine and see if the issue still occurs)

I appreciate there isn't much to go on here but I'm hoping that someone might be able to give me some pointers as to what else I should check, as I've been banging my head against this for most of the day.

My background is with Ruby on Rails so, as with that framework, I've a feeling that there is a lot of "magic" happening behind-the-scenes that is making it very tricky to figure out what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to see documents while developing because of

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    ...
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Like `static` files `media` files should be handled on server level. For example, if you are using GCP you need to update your `app.yaml` and add `media/` the same way as `static/`

```
...

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/
  - url: /media
    static_dir: media/

...
```